# Combinatorics and permutations with the set {1,...,n}

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm working on the following problem.
Let some positive integer $n \geq 1$ and fix another integer $k$ in $[1,n]$  
Assume $A_k$ is the event "none of the number 1,2,...,k-1" occurs before $k$ after shuffling $\{1,...,n\}$ 
I want to prove that $P(A_k) = 1/k$ . I denoted $C_k(n)$ all the possible permutation that verifies the property described in the event such that $ P(A_k) = C_k(n)/n! $ and then by examining the position of $k$ between the position $1$ and $n-k+1$ I found $ C_k(n) = (n-1)! + (n-k) (n-2)! + (n-k)(n-k-1)(n-3)! + \dots + (n-k)! (k-1)! $ which can be rewritten as $C_k(n) = (n-1)! + (n-k) C_k(n-1)$ (note : $C_k(p) = 0$ if $p < k$) 
From this, it is sufficient to prove that $ C_k(n) = n!/k$ to get te result 
Assuming that $k=n$ then obviously $C_k(n) = (n-1)!$ and $P(A_k)=(n-1)!/n!=1/n$, so the result is true for $k=n$
Assuming that $k \leq n-1$ then we can see that from $ C_k(n)/n! = 1/n + (n-k)/k C_k(n-1)/(n-1)!$ if we prove that $ P(A_k) = C_k(n-1)/(n-1)!$ then we are done because then $ P(A_k)=1/n+(n-k)/n P(A_k)$ solves as $P(A_k)=1/k$
Anyway, I'm pretty sure there is a more straightforward way of solving this ... any advices ? 
Also, how would you prove that $\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}$ is an independent family of events ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First choose $k$ positions out of $n$. Now place integer $k$ in the leftmost of the chosen positions. Place integers $1$ to $k-1$ in rest of the $(k-1)$ positions. Except integer $k$ which has to be in the leftmost of the chosen positions, rest can be permuted in $(k-1)!$ ways. Now rest of the $(n-k)$ integers can be permuted in rest of the $(n-k)$ positions in $(n-k)!$ ways.

Unrestricted permutations $= n!$

So desired probability $ = \frac{{n \choose k} (k-1)! \, (n-k)!}{n!} = \frac{1}{k}$.

Now if this is not intuitive, you can look at the following -

For integers $1$ to $(k-1)$ to be on the right of integer $k$, there has to be at least $(k-1)$ places to the right of integer k.

So integer $k$ can be in positions $1$ to $(n-k+1)$.

For each position $j$, choose $(j-1)$ of the $(n-k)$ integers (larger than $k$) and place to the left of $k$ in $(j-1)$ places. You can permute left to the $k$ in $(j-1)!$ ways and right to $k$ in $(n-j)!$ ways.

So, desired probability $= \displaystyle \sum \limits_{j=1}^{n-k+1} \frac{ ^{n-k}P_{j-1} \, (n-j)!}{n!} = \sum \limits_{j=1}^{n-k+1} \frac{(n-k)! \, (n-j)!}{n! \, (n-k-j+1)!}$

You put this expression in WolframAlpha and it simplifies it to $\frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: Nice ! I like the first technique :-) Now I’m trying to figure out why the events are independent :/

Answer (score 0):

The result can be proved by induction over $n$. To go from $n$ to $n + 1$: If $k = n + 1$ then $n + 1$ must come first, the probability of which is $1/(n + 1)$. If $k \le n$ then it doesn't matter where $n + 1$ is inserted, so the probability is still $1/k$.

Comment: Oh indeed, I see what you mean... so my computation were useless :-( . What about the independent stuff ?

Comment: Well, I think the same sort of argument would apply. When going from n to n + 1, we can think of it as inserting n + 1 into a permutation of 1, 2, ..., n. Its position can neither affect, nor be affected by, any relations that 1, ..., n may have among themselves.